# Does google maps in android allow any integration? Say long press on a point, or click an address

Tags: android, google-maps

I know you can embed the google maps view in an android activity, but is it possible to plug anything into the actual google maps app.  say if somebody clicked on a result in the map, and instead of the standard screen show a list of options, like when you share an image.  Like "tag this".  Something like that.

I can't seem to find any info on that.  Its all on integrating MapView into your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge that's not possible. You cannot program your own copy of Google Maps (that would incorporate the features that you want to add) either, because it's one of the proprietary Google Apps (like the Gmail-, YouTube-, and Market-apps), for which they don't release the code.

Comment: Apps like gmail, etc, generally post intents to the system for certain activities.  So, you could register your app as one that could respond to those intents.  Like attaching files to an email.  That sort of thing.  I'm not talking about replacing the app, of course.